# How to replace a form by displaying a result on the same page in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, replace, components

My code below can run the result, link the calculation form to the result page well. However, what I want is to replace the form when clicking the button "calculate saving range" by displaying the result on the same page. It looks like the picture below

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjx7N.png)

My code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/calculation-form-uxip8?file=/src/components/Calculator.jsx

Calculator.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { Button, Form, Row, Col, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

class Calculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      
      squareFootage: ""
      
    };
  }

  

  handleSquare = (event) => {
    this.setState({ squareFootage: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isOpen: true,
      value:
        "$" +
        Math.floor(1.69 * this.state.squareFootage * (10 / 100)) +
        "- $" +
        Math.floor(1.69 * this.state.squareFootage * (30 / 100))
    });
  };

  closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="calculator">
        <h1> CALCULATION FORM </h1>
        <Form className="form-horizontal">
       
            
         

          <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formHorizontalFootage">
            <Form.Label column sm={6}>
              Square footage of buildings*
            </Form.Label>
            <Col sm={6}>
              <Form.Control
                type="squareFootage"
                placeholder="sq ft"
                value={this.state.squareFootage}
                onChange={this.handleSquare}
                required
              />
              <div style={{ fontSize: 14, color: "red" }}>
                {this.state.squareFootageError}
              </div>
              <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                Please input a number, e.g. 12300
              </Form.Text>
            </Col>
          </Form.Group>

         

          <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Calculate your Savings Range
          </Button>

          <Form.Text className="text-muted">* Required Field</Form.Text>
        </Form>
        <Modal
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            float: "left",
            left: "50%",
            top: "50%",
            transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
          }}
          show={this.state.isOpen}
          value={this.state.value}
          onHide={this.closeModal}
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>RESULT</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <h2>You could save between</h2>
          <h1>{this.state.value} Annually</h1>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Calculator;
```

Is there anyone who has any idea to replace a form with result information on the same page? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This would just be a conditional view such as `<div>{ condition ? <div>true</div> : <div>false</div>}</div>`

Comment: where can I put it? can you explain clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the modal and add a condition operator to toggle between form content and your result.

Here is what your return method should look like

```
return (
  <div className="calculator">
    <h1> CALCULATION FORM </h1>
    {
      /*Condition*/ !this.state.isOpen ? (
        /** if true return form */
        <Form className="form-horizontal">
          <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formHorizontalFootage">
            <Form.Label column sm={6}>
              Square footage of buildings*
            </Form.Label>
            <Col sm={6}>
              <Form.Control
                type="squareFootage"
                placeholder="sq ft"
                value={this.state.squareFootage}
                onChange={this.handleSquare}
                required
              />
              <div style={{ fontSize: 14, color: "red" }}>{this.state.squareFootageError}</div>
              <Form.Text className="text-muted">Please input a number, e.g. 12300</Form.Text>
            </Col>
          </Form.Group>
          <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Calculate your Savings Range</Button>

          <Form.Text className="text-muted">* Required Field</Form.Text>
        </Form>
      ) : (
        /** else return your result div */
        <div>
          <h2>You could save between</h2>
          <h1>{this.state.value} Annually</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }
  </div>
);
```

Here’s the react documentation on the jsx conditional rendering

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

You going to use the condition operator

```
<MyComponent>
 {conditionCount > 0 
  ? <IfComponent/>
   : <ElseComponent/>}// make sure to wrap with the bracket {}
</MyComponent>
```

Comment: could you try here? there is an error https://codesandbox.io/s/calculation-form-uxip8?file=/src/components/Calculator.jsx

Comment: Looks like you miss place the condition literal. Here are fixed https://codesandbox.io/s/calculation-form-forked-gcqho?file=/src/components/Calculator.jsx

Comment: Inside <ElseComponent/>, i want to have a link back to <IfComponent/>, can I put  <NavLink to="/">Use Calculator Again</NavLink>, where <Route exact path="/" component={Calculator} /> in App.js?

Comment: You cannot use route link to navigate back because this conditional rendering is happened under the same route same component. However, you can make a button to toggle this.state.isOpen to false to hide result and show the calculator again.

Comment: Could you try in the code sand box so it is easy for me to follow?

Comment: I used it  <button onClick={!this.state.isOpen}>Use Calculator again</button> but it does not work. Could you fix it?

Comment: acutally, i fixed this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: np, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using isOpen to show the result Modal.
Let's change your render function a little bit to something like this

```
render() {
    return (!isOpen ? <YourForm /> : <Result />)
}
```

You should change isOpen to something like isSubmitted in this case